# Moving same extension files from entire volume(partition) to a single folder

Tags: copy, xcopy

Can I move files from entire volume to a single folder. Like I'm working on c++ now a days and I have more than 300 *.cpp files in my 80GB partition(including folders and subfolders). I want to gather them at one place. is there any shortcut way to do that?

<s>using cmd</s>

> <s>move *.cpp "new folder"</s>

This CMD method is only to move from one folder to another.

Answer (score 0):

I got a way myself.
I enabled the "Show hidden extensions" from the folder options,then searched for **.cpp**. then Selected all of them by pressing **Ctrl+A** . After that I pressed **Ctrl+x** then pasted them in a new folder.